# How to calculate spilling factor in VASP?

Tags: vasp, density-of-states, vaspkit

I have noticed very big differences in VASP calculations for the TDOS and PDOS, post-processed with VASPKIT. I have read that could happen because of spilling of electrons.

However, I was wondering how to quantify this error practically in a VASP calculation.

Comment: In QE there is a parameter called the spilling parameter which will tell you whether the wavefunctions of your structure are rather different from superposition of atomic wavefunctions in the pseudopotentials, I think that's what you are looking for, and as far as I know there is no such parameter out of the box in VASP. I am not sure how QE would find that parameter (maybe from the overlap matrix).